Sum of random phase sin functions
let's take the sum of sin functions with the same period but different phases
$$
Y = \sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{2000}\sin\left(3x + \phi_{i}\right)
$$
where $\quad x \in \left[0,2\pi\right]\quad$ and
$\quad\phi \sim {\cal U}\left[0,2\pi\right]$.
I was expecting Y to be :

a line centered around zero since the + and - part of random phased sin function will cancel each other out.
Or a randomly evolving function.

But not a regular $\sin\left(3x + \phi\right)$ function.
Can someone explain why we end up with a very clear sin function? (as the phase is a random number)
here's the code in case,
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360)

for i in range(1,2000):
    exec(f"y{i} = 2*np.sin(3*x+np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi))")
    exec(f"plt.plot(x, y{i})")

z=1
for i in range(1,2000):
    exec(f"z = z+y{i}")

print(len(z))
plt.plot(x,z,color='k')


case for adding 20 sin functions


What’s the reason for using exec?

you are summing a bunch of functions with the same periodicity. It stands to reason you will get a periodic function. If you are familiar with trigonometric identities, the reason for the sin is also obvious.

@Aruralreader i used exec to avoid to declare 2000 sine functions manually, that was the first quickest method that came into my mind. Maybe not the best.

@user619894 sorry, been a while I'm not doing maths. It's a bit difficult to intuite that fast.

Using Euler's identity, a sum of two arbitrary sine functions may be expressed as
\begin{align}
A_1\sin(kx+\phi_1)+A_2\sin(kx+\phi_2)
&=\operatorname{Im}[A_1 e^{i(kx+\phi_1)}+A_2 e^{i(kx+\phi_2)}]\\
&=\operatorname{Im}[e^{i kx}(A_1 e^{i\phi_1}+A_2 e^{i\phi_2})]
\end{align}
Since $A_1 e^{i\phi_1},A_2e^{i\phi_2}$ are complex numbers, their sum is also some complex number $A'e^{i\phi'}$. Hence
$$A_1\sin(kx+\phi_1)+A_2\sin(kx+\phi_2)=A' \sin(kx+\phi')$$
That is, the sum of two arbitrary sine functions is another sine function with the same periodicity. Adding further sine functions will further change the phase and amplitude, but the periodicity remains unchanged.

to push farther the reasoning : In my case all the $A_i = A$, all amplitudes are the same, so $Y = Im[Ae^{ikx}\sum_{j} e^{i\phi_{j}}]$. If we sum up complex numbers on a circle ($\phi \in [0,2\pi]$) we will end up with $0$, because each point on a circle will cancel with its opposit, so $Y=0$. In my case I take points uniformly distributed on a circle, so I was expecting that by analogy the opposite values will cancel

@Artashes It's true that $\sum_j e^{i\phi_j}$ averages to zero. But $\sum_j e^{i\phi_j}$ need not vanish for some set of $N$ independent random phases, and indeed it's vanishingly unlikely that this is true for any particular such random set. (Just because one of the phases is $\phi$ in a given random sample doesn't mean that $\phi+\pi$ must also occur.)

I got it , even if one particular phase will survive and all the other vanish the result will still remain a sine function $Y = Im[A e^{ikx} e^{i\phi_{347}}]$

@Artashes Correct. Another signature of this is to look at the amplitude of your output: the result may always be a sine function, but the amplitude of each result can and will vary.
